# sonar 3.1 javascript issue

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

in sonar 2.5, there is jit-yc.js file in javascript folder.
this js file is used to develop the radiator plugin. But this file is removed from sonar 3.1.
 is there any other js file same as jit.jy.js in sonar3.1. I need this file to build a plugin.
Is there any other way to use this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins can provide static files like images, CSS or JS files. They have to be copied in src/main/resources/static and then can by accessible from the public URL :
http:///static//

You can read more here : http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Extend+Web+Application#ExtendWebApplication-Staticfiles

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used  this idea in my local mechine and its working perfectly. but it's not working on jenkins.

Comment: Jenkins? Am I miss something. Don't you implement a Sonar plugin?

Comment: junkins is an other server i am working with.. this query is not working there